# error TS2304: cannot find $ in angular 5 component

Tags: jquery, html, typescript, jquery-selectors, angular5

I have a side-navbar in angular component which expands on click similar to [this](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_sidenav.asp). The HTML snippet used to create the navbar is :

**HTML:**

As the name(`openNav()`) suggests, the following HTML code **will expand the navbar**:

```
<div>
    <img (click)="openNav()" src="/imagepath" id="image">
</div>
```

And the following HTML code  **will close the navbar**:

```
<div id="mySidenav" class="sidenav">
    <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto" id="sidenavContent">
        <li class="nav-item" id="close-btn">
            <img class="closebtn" (click)="closeNav()" id="white-cross" src="/assets/imagepath">
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item" id="close-btn">
           <p> Item 1 </p>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
            <p> Item 2 </p>
        </li>

    </ul>
</div>
```

**Typescript:**

The typescript used is:

```
openNav() 
 {
     $("#mySidenav").css("width", "50%");   // Line A
 }

 closeNav() 
 {
    $("#mySidenav").css("width", "0%");   // Line B
 }
```

The above typescript code is not included in the `ngOnInit()` function.

**Problem Statement :**

As soon as I do `ng serve` on my command prompt, I get the following error:

> error TS2304: Cannot find name '$'.

The **$ represents** the lines (**Line A and Line B** in the typescript above) inside **openNav() and closeNav() functions above** in the typescript.

I am wondering what are the primary reasons behind that error **as sometimes I get the error and sometimes I don't while doing ng-serve**.

Comment: try this line at the top in typescript file  **declare var $:any**

Comment: @NehaTawar Its already there. By using this line, sometimes I get the error, sometimes I doesn't.

Comment: @Neha Tawar Is there any particular reason, why I sometimes get the error and sometimes I doesn't  ?

Comment: Might be because  the file in which you have used $ is getting executed before the jquery gets imported and $ gets its value.Check ones the flow/order in which thing are getting interpreted.

Comment: That file is used where all my components are **inside my app folder**. I am wondering in which folder I can see my jquery. How can I check which one is executed 1st ?

Comment: Hi I have replied on the discussion please check the comment and let me know if you have any issues.

Comment: @NehaTawar I have replied there. I am wondering where I have to import `import $ from "JQuery"`  ? Is there any specific file I have to import that ?

Comment: Use in each file where ever you want to use jquery just import $ from "JQuery" and also go through https://medium.com/@NetanelBasal/typescript-integrate-jquery-plugin-in-your-project-e28c6887d8dc

Comment: @NehaTawar On the top of the file, you want me to import `import $ from "JQuery"`  ? Right ?

Comment: yes try if this solves your error

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/169947/discussion-between-user5447339-and-neha-tawar).

Comment: don't use jquery. you allready have great component based library in use just use its functionality you loose grear deal of performance.

Comment: @JimiPajala Will keep this in mind for future. But at this moment, can we resolve that error ?

Comment: try use jQuey or JQuery names insted of $ mark. otherwise if this is just linter error declare $ mark as global in tsconfig.

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/jquery do you have this  on your package.json?

Comment: I did `npm install @types/jquery --save-dev` after `Oscar` recommended me as you can see below. I am wondering what I need to do more.

Answer (score 1):

I assume that `$` is `jQuery`. You must add `jQuery` to your dependencies and imported it in the file where you're using it. I'd suggest also adding the type definitions for jQuery: `npm install @types/jquery --save-dev`

If you're importing jQuery in any other way, then just add the types.

Comment: Just checking where do I need to do `npm install @types/jquery --save-dev` ? On the path where node_modules is installed ?

Comment: I am not sure by this line `If you're importing jQuery in any other way, then just add the types`. Can you elaborate more on that ?

Comment: I mean, if you're adding a link to the jQuery lib directly from the HTML, so jQuery will be available, just TypeScript doesn't know about it.

Comment: Do I need to do `npm install @types/jquery --save-dev` in the node_modules path ?

Comment: No, in the project root. From the same point where you execute `ng serve`. But make sure you have jQuery in your project, some way or the other, or you'll get a runtime error.

Comment: After doing this `npm install @types/jquery --save-dev`, I got this message `added 69 packages in 53.906s` but still I am getting the same error.

Comment: In your `tsconfig.json` you must have something like: `typeRoots: ["node_modules/@types"]`. Do you have it?

Comment: I checked now, Yes, I have it.

Comment: Is there any reason, why I am still getting the same error ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/169799/discussion-between-user5447339-and-oscar-paz).

Answer (score 0):

This is a possible solution:

**HTML:**

```
<div>
<img (click)="openNav()" src="/imagepath" id="image">
</div>
And the following HTML code will close the navbar:

<div id="mySidenav" class="sidenav" style="{{vstyle}}">
  <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto" id="sidenavContent">
    <li class="nav-item" id="close-btn">
      <img class="closebtn" (click)="closeNav()" id="white-cross" src="/assets/imagepath">
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item" id="close-btn">
      <p> Item 1 </p>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <p> Item 2 </p>
    </li>

  </ul>
</div>
```

**Typescript:**

```
//Define a visual style variable
vstyle: = 'width:50%;';


openNav() 
 {
     vstyle = 'width:50%;';   // Line A
 }

 closeNav() 
 {
    vstyle = 'width:0%;';   // Line A
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the jquery in ts file, declare $ as a variable of type any, then you won't get the error.

declare  var $:any

Answer (score 0):

Use style.width

```
<div id="mySidenav"  [style.width]="myWidthVariable+'%'" class="sidenav">
<ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto" id="sidenavContent">
    <li class="nav-item" id="close-btn">
        <img class="closebtn" (click)="closeNav()" id="white-cross" src="/assets/imagepath">
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item" id="close-btn">
       <p> Item 1 </p>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
        <p> Item 2 </p>
    </li>

</ul>
```

And then set the value of "myWidthVariable" on your openNav() and closeNav() methods (just the number).